# Proving some derivative properties

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I want to prove the following for $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$.

(1) If $f$ differentiable in $(a,b)$, and $\lim_{x \to a+} f'(x)$ exists, then $f'(a)$ exists.

(2) If $f'(z)$ exists for $z \in (a,b)$ and  one-sided limits $\lim_{x \to z+} f'(x)$ and  $\lim_{x\to z-}f'(x)$ exist, then both are equal to $f'(z)$.

(3) The upper Dini derivative $D^+f = \limsup_{h \to 0+} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ exists although possibly with value $+\infty$. If $f$ is continuous but not differentiable it is not possible that $D^+f(x) = + \infty$ at every point in $(a,b)$.

I proved (1) with mean value theorem since $\lim_{h \to 0+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0+} f'(c) = f'(a)$ where $a < c < a+h$.  I also know that (2) can be proved with Darboux theorem implying derivative cannot have a jump discontinuity.

Supposedly using (2) we can answer (3), but I am unable to proceed.

Comment: 2) is false. Not all derivatives are continuous functions.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Sorry. I left out a condition that both the left and right limits of the derivative also exist.My problem is really with (3).

Comment: I know -- I mentioned Darboux theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an outline of a possible proof for (3), though it doesn't really use (2):

Suppose, to the contrary, that we did have $D^+ f(x) = +\infty$ for every $x \in [a, b)$.

- Fix a positive real number $M$, and define $A_M := \{ x \in [a, b] \mid f(x) - f(a) \ge M (x - a) \}$.  Then $a \in A_M$ and $A_M$ is bounded above by $b$, so $\sup A_M$ exists.
- Show that $A_M$ is closed, so $\sup A_M \in A_M$.
- Show that if $\sup A_M < b$, then using the assumption $D^+ f(\sup A_M) = \infty$, we can get a contradiction.

Now, from the fact that $b \in A_M$ no matter how large $M$ is, derive a contradiction.

(And then, to show it's also impossible to have $D^+ f(x) = +\infty$ for every $x \in (a, b)$, apply the result you prove above to the restriction of $f$ to $[\frac{a+b}{2}, b]$.)

Comment: Thank you -- this clears it up.  I see no connection with (2) either.