Proving that continuous functions cannot have $D^+f(x)=\infty$ for all $x$
I have been given to prove that no continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ can have $D^+f(x)=\infty$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, where
$$D^+f(x_0)=\limsup_{x\to x_0+}{\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}}.$$
I have spent a long time trying to come up with an argument but nothing has worked so far. I was thinking I would be done if I could show that if two points $a$ and $b$ have $D^+f(a)=\infty$ and $D^+f(b)=\infty$ then there must exist a $c\in(a,b)$ such that $D^+f(c)<\infty$, but I'm having trouble.
Any guidance (even just hints) would be greatly appreciated.

See property (3) in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3190492/42969
